# How Win11 decides the default File Save As Location with TSaveDialog that has ofNoChangeDir flag (Win32 Delphi App)

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

There is a problem when saving the PDF file, the default "last used folder" may be sometimes set by OS to a folder that does not respond and this causes my app to hang when opening SaveAs Dialog with Win32 api.

Now one client has an issue that the remembered default folder is causing a weird hanging. I need to reset this default last used path somehow, without changing the code block (see below).

How is the OS choosing and remembering this default path?
It seems OS remembers my previous folder selection when EXE is started again. My win32 app is using chdir() to change the default path to the location of exe inside "program files x86", but the OS does not seem to give that folder as a default location to SaveAs dialog. Also, the Icon/Shortcut has the Start in folder setting, but its not used either.

My app does not itself store the default path changed by end-user, but still when I come back to save PDF file next time,  the app somehow remembers the exactly same path, that was used earlier.

```
FileOpenDialog := TSaveDialog.create(parent);
FileOpenDialog.DefaultExt := '*.pdf';
FileOpenDialog.filename := 'Report';
FileOpenDialog.Filter := 'PDF Document (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Bitmap image (*.bmp)|*.bmp';
FileOpenDialog.options := [ofNoChangeDir,ofPathMustExist,ofHideReadOnly,ofNoReadOnlyReturn ,ofOverwritePrompt   ];
FileOpenDialog.title := 'Save PDF';
if not FileOpenDialog.Execute then exit;
```

I have searched the whole Registry but cannot find where OS is saving the "last used folder".

Comment: The Windows API can clear persisted data using `IFileDialog::ClearClientData` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-clearclientdata) not sure if/how this is accessible from your delphi classes.

Comment: Related: [The SetClientGuid method of the common file and folder dialogs lets you give names to those dialogs, too](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200527-00/?p=103801). Though, honestly, if a client managed to install software on their system that renders File Explorer partially unusable then that's an issue this specific client needs to solve. This cannot be solved by your application.

Comment: You know that [`.Filename` can hold a full path](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.FileName), too? That could indirectly browse the dialog to the intended folder, and if not, pressing the "save" button would still give back that full path with filename. There's no need to **only** operate on relative filenames.

Comment: `TSaveDialog` wraps the old `GetSaveFileName()` API. On Vista+, you really should use `TFileSaveDialog` instead, which wraps the `IFileSaveDialog` API. That gives you a little more control over the dialog and its persistence. As for the persistence itself, the data is stored in binary form in this Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\CIDSizeMRU`

Comment: Excellent @RemyLebeau for pointing out the registry hive,  is there any method to reset these easily, it seems these keys are linking to a name of exe,  so renaming my exe would help  Or would it be safe to delete the whole key  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\CIDSizeMRU   if its some kind of cache?

Comment: Thanks also for pointing out the TFileSaveDialog

Comment: Probably one of the problems when outdated programming software is used on a ~20 years more modern OS

Comment: @Tom do not delete the whole key. Yes, it's a cache, but it's a cache you don't own, and multiple apps store data in there. The correct solution is to use the IFileSaveDialog API with its SetClientGuid() and ClearClientData() methods.